# SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(string sddlForm)

Tags: c#, security, dacl

I dont find any usefull website according to this API.

What's the format of the String? The content?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Security Descriptor String Format is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379570(VS.85).aspx)